# CSS: hover событие для ::-webkit-scrollbar элемента?

Tags: javascript, html

Возможно ли методами CSS сделать hover событие для ::-webkit-scrollbar элемента? Или надо это поведение описывать при помощью флагов и определении позиции мыши?

Comment: Поведение должно быть таким, чтобы при наведении на полосу прокрутки применялся cursor:pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если вы имеете ввиду стилизацию полосы прокрутки с помощью css то можно так как css3 тоже поддерживает некоторую работу в этом плане!! вот пример

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
background-image:url('');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:5px;
height:0px
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background-color:#ecedee
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
background-color:#6dc0c8;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background-color:#56999f;
}

::-webkit-resizer{
background-image:url('');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:4px;
height:0px
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{
width: 4px;
}
Чисто на css без js.
```

Comment: моя почта если нужно sektor162s@mail.ru

Comment: Капец я точно пробовал также но не получалось. Терь сделал и получилось... капец... По всей видимости я когда делал наводку на thumb у меня не было бара, а когда пробовал делать на весь скроллбар то у меня был thumb на весь скролл...  Ахаха ну да ладно. спасибо.

Comment: "Георгий Грибов, ховер работает. Но стиль почему то не срабатывает. Хотелось бы чтобы при наведении на скроллбар срабатывал cursor: pointer; Но он почему то не срабатывает...